# 2D array of labels

Tags: vb.net

The following gives me a nullreference error. How can i accomplish this simple task while avoiding the error?

thanks!

Edit: L1,L2,etc are labels in my form.

```
Dim labelArray(,) As Label = {{L1, L2, L3, L4}, {L5, L6, L7, L8}, {L9, L10, L11, L12}, {L13, L14, L15, L16}}


private sub button_click(stuff that goes in here)
labelArray(zeroPoint.X, zeroPoint.Y).BackColor = Color.LimeGreen
end sub
```

EDIT: I got it to work by doing the following inside the form load method..

```
labelArray(0, 0) = Me.L1
    labelArray(0, 1) = Me.L2
    labelArray(0, 2) = Me.L3
    labelArray(0, 3) = Me.L4

    labelArray(1, 0) = Me.L5
    labelArray(1, 1) = Me.L6
    labelArray(1, 2) = Me.L7
    labelArray(1, 3) = Me.L8

    labelArray(2, 0) = Me.L9
    labelArray(2, 1) = Me.L10
    labelArray(2, 2) = Me.L11
    labelArray(2, 3) = Me.L12

    labelArray(3, 0) = Me.L13
    labelArray(3, 1) = Me.L14
    labelArray(3, 2) = Me.L15
    labelArray(3, 3) = Me.L16
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your label array initializer runs before the InitializeComponent() method, where all your labels are instantiated. You are effectively adding a bunch of null references to the array.

Leave the array declaration where it is, but move the assignment code to the end of the form's constructor, and I think that will fix the problem.

Beyond that, you'll need to check the zeropoint.X and zeropoint.Y result in valid indexes. Remember that, by default, vb.net indexes work a little different than either C# or VB6.

Comment: @rage vb6 was one-indexed by default rather than zero-indexed. vb.net is zero-indexed by default, like C#. When declaring a new array in c# (ie: `new string[6]`), the six in that snippet refers to the number of items in the array. For the "equivalent" `New String(6)` in VB.Net, the six is the last index, for a total of seven items.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
Dim labelArray(,)
Private Sub button_click(stuff that goes in here)
    labelArray = New Label(,) {{l1, l2, l3, l4}, {l5, l6, l7, l8}, {l9, l10, l11, l12}, {l13, l14, l15, l16}}
    labelArray(zeroPoint.X, zeroPoint.Y).BackColor = Color.LimeGreen
End Sub
```

Comment: I still get the following error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"